# Applescript subroutine

Tags: applescript

I have a helperScript which has a few basic functions that I frequently use.

My Current script’s flow goes like this:

```
on SubA()
    Set HelperScript to load…..
    tell HelperScript
    : :
        : :
    end tell
end SubA

on SubB()
    Set HelperScript to load…..

    tell HelperScript
    ::
        ::
    end tell
end SubB

on run paravlist
    Set HelperScript to load…..

    tell HelperScript

    SubA()

    SubB()

    end tell
end run
```

I am unable to call SubA() and SubB() as the helper script is being set and used from each of subroutines. If I comment out the usage of helperScript. I am able to call subroutines from one another. What is the best way to deal with a problem like this? I want to use the helperScript in every subroutine.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "I am unable to call SubA() and SubB()..."? What is the error you get, or what does not work as expected and why.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question a few more times, I think I've figured out what you're asking. You're trying to load a script within your method and then you want to call a method that is within that script?

If that is the case, I think what you're looking for is this...

```
set HelperScript to load script...
set theResult to someMethod() of HelperScript
```

**EDIT :** 
I'm still not clear if you have two scripts or one, so i've updated the answer to reflect both cases.

**Dual script example...**

```
property HelperScript : null

on run
    try
        if not loadScript() then error "Unable to load script"

        set rslt1 to SubA() of HelperScript -- This approach assumes HelperScript.scpt is a different script and it contains a method called SubA
        set rslt2 to SubB() of HelperScript -- This approach assumes HelperScript.scpt is a different script and it contains a method called SubB

    on error errMsg
        activate
        display dialog "Error: " & errMsg buttons {"OK"} default button 1 giving up after 10
    end try
end run


on loadScript()
    try
        set HelperScript to load script (POSIX file "/Path/To/HelperScript.scpt")
        return true
    on error
        return false
    end try
end loadScript
```

**Single script example...**

```
on run
    try
        set rslt1 to SubA() -- This approach assumes your HelperScript is THIS script
        set rslt2 to SubB() -- This approach assumes your HelperScript is THIS script
    on error errMsg
        activate
        display dialog "Error: " & errMsg buttons {"OK"} default button 1 giving up after 10
    end try
end run

on SubA()
    try
        -- Do something here

        return true -- or some other value
    on error
        return false -- or some other value
    end try
end SubA

on SubB()
    try
        -- Do something here

        return true -- or some other value
    on error
        return false -- or some other value
    end try
end SubB
```

Comment: Sorry that I lacked information. I got the error:    error "«script» doesn’t understand the “SubA” message." number -1708 from «script»

Comment: I am doing it as you suggested. I still get the error. The problem here I think is having declared and using the helperScript in each of the subroutine. Is there a way I can just globally declare it and use it all of the subroutines?

Comment: @AnuRV - See the updated answer for two different cases, I wasn't exactly sure which you were trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript has included a [library loading system](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_script_objects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH207-SW6) since 10.9. It's not great (e.g. avoid the SDEF garbage as it's 1. make-work and 2. bug-injector) but it generally does the job. I recommend you adopt that.